# Session deleted after logout button pressed

Tags: perl

I am developing an application in perl, and i want to make the the session once the log out button clicked. So, when the user logged out, then they can not back to web just by press the back button. I have tried it with session flush and session delete but it still doesnt work.

`if( $cgi->param('login_submit') eq 'Logout' )`

```
{
    #Session beim Logout zerstören
    $session->delete();
    $session->flush();

}
```

thanks

Comment: Does your code definitely go into the block? Have you tried outputing some debug in there, to make sure it is actually calling $session->delete() and $session->flush() ?

Comment: yup, i did it, i even print the session, and it prints nothing, but everytime i press the back button in browser, it will return to the account opened before

Comment: Is it only by going back that you are able to return to the account? Can you access the account by clicking on links/submitting forms?

Comment: yup, this is so weird, i dont know how to solve it

Comment: I wasn't very clear in my question. Is it ONLY when you click back that you can access the account?

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you have a cron job that goes through deleting session files from `/tmp` or `the folder which stores the session data` based on file age to deal with sessions that expired where the user did not logout.
As well as make sure not to run out of space or have the wrong data to .....

You might want to refer to
http://search.cpan.org/~sherzodr/CGI-Session-3.95/Session/Tutorial.pm#DELETING_A_SESSION